# Duplicate finder (Resharper) stackoverflow exception / Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, teamcity, stack-overflow, command-line-tool, dupfinder

When I try to run a duplicate finder (Resharper), I am getting an error process terminated due to StackOverflow exception

[StackOverflow Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGgbD.png)

Comment: Most likely, it is a recursive loop without a terminating condition, or the call stack is simply growing too large.  There could be any number of possible reasons it is occurring.